# Is it possible to get " raw " data from Google Analytics, then to group the data yourself?

Tags: metrics, dimensions

I need to get data from one query using 13 dimensions and 13 metrics. Because of the limitation, I can't do that. Q: is it possible to get raw data or how can you combine data from multiple queries with different dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Analytics Standard, then there is no way to fetch 13 dimensions in a single query. But if you have Google Analytics 360 aka Premium version then you can link your GA 360 account to BigQuery and then you can  fetch such data using sql from BigQuery.

Having said that, there is a way for standard as well but its feasibility depends the kind of data you would want to fetch. You can use segment features if possible by creating a segment based on some of the dimensions and rest dimensions ( 5 maximum) can be put in custom report. For example if you want to fetch data such as sessions, transactions, bounce rate, time spent and other metrics on the basis of Gender type: Male, Device: desktop, Country: India, Age: 25-34, Browser: Chrome, and other dimensions are generic with no filters such as source, medium, event action, landing page and etc. Then, you can create a segment based on dimensions which sort of have filter criteria as per your requirement and use other dimensions which don't have filter criteria in custom report.But remember, the feasibility of this solution depends on your requirement.